# USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED only startsActivity of Galaxy S3 ICS

Tags: android, usb

Recently I've been trying to receive the intent android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED using a broadcast receiver as per all the samples and examples that I've seen.

I've declared a reciever in the manifest;

```
<receiver android:name=".UsbDeviceReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" 
                android:resource="@xml/device_filter"/>
```

I have also done similar in the activity code - onStart and OnStop register/unregister the receiver.

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED);

    registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);
```

However, I am finding that the intent is just caught. Observing logcat I can see that attaching a usb device looks for activities to start, while detaching broadcasts the detatch intent. According to the aforementioned samples, this should not be the case.

Am I missing something drastic concerning metadata? I have no problems at all with android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED. Perhaps this is a bug with the android version installed on the galaxy s3? Perhaps this is an ICS 'feature'.

Any relavent information is welcome!

Comment: The code (see for example) https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/java/com/android/server/usb/UsbSettingsManager.java does not send a broadcast on device attachment, it only starts the activity specifically registered to handle that device.  Someone submitted a patch on gerrit to send the broadcast but it seems to have been declined due to a mismatch with the design philosophy.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the concise reply. It is a relief that this is not just an issue with my device. Does the patch submission still exist so that I could read in more detail the reasons for this behaviour? My workaround at the moment is going to involve an invisible activity and my own broadcast. It feels like a hack. I will post the code when I'm done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known defect:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25701

and here:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25703

But don't hold your breath waiting for it to be fixed. While you're looking at the bug report, star it so you'll get notified of updates to the report. Likely that will be comments from other people asking for it to be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the links Dave. I have resigned myself to having to workaround. I schedule a regular task to observe usb while the activity is resumed. I don't like doing it and it probably isn't great for battery but it works quite happily.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround that I have found for `USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED` is to just have a button that calls my `OpenAccessory(accessory)` method again and that seems to be working for me. Maybe that will work for `USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED` as well. Just have a device connnected/not connected status somewhere and if it is not connected the user can just hit that button.

Edit: I have found that putting `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in the manifest seems to "register" the intent of `USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED`, though it never shows up as such it does work as if thats what it is doing.

Answer (score 1):

you can declare intent filter in the manifest as explained here:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html

then you catch android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED in onResume()
or in onNewIntent().

when your activity is running and you attach your usb Device, main intent is thrown to onResume() but android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED to the onNewIntent(). Adjust your code according to that.

you can declare onNewIntent() as follows:

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) 
    {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        System.out.println("onNewIntent" + intent.getAction());
        if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        mDevice = (UsbDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        if(mDevice!= null)
            mUsbManager.requestPermission(mDevice, mPermissionIntent);
        }
    }
```

and onResume() similarly.

tested on android 4.0.4
Device: Samsung Galaxy tab 750